# How to launch one activity test cases from another in espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am very new to Espresso. I am writitng test cases for android application.
My  question is how to launch second activity's test cases from First activity.

Test cases of First activty is as follows

```
    package venki.estest;


import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.squareup.spoon.Spoon;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.clearText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.isDialog;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;


/**
 * Created by ${venkie} on ${28/1/16}.
 */

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class Login {
    private MainActivity mActivity;



    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class,true);
    private static final String URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/4v3nc;";
    private static final String EXPECTED="{\"Hello\":\"qwworld\"}";
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mActivity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void emailIsInvalid() {
       // Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("invalid"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).check(matches(withError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email))));
      //  Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");
    }


    @Test
    public void emailIsEmpty() {
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText(""),closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).check(matches(withError(getString(R.string.error_field_required))));
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");
    }
    @Test
    public void passwordIsEmpty() {
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");

        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("email@email.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(clearText());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).check(matches(withError(getString(R.string.error_field_required))));
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");

    }

    @Test
    public void passwordIsTooShort() {
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");

        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("email@email.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("1234"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).check(matches(withError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password))));
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");

    }
    @Test
    public void checkDeviceRegistered() throws IOException {

      //  Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");

        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("omoto.test1@gmail.com"));
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("password"));
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        String response = calltoBackend();
        try {
            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String resString = responseObject.getString("status");
            if (resString.equalsIgnoreCase("NODEVICENAME")){
                onView(withText(R.string.my_title))
                        .inRoot(isDialog()) // <---
                        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       /* OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        okhttp3.Request request=new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();
        Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();

        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED, response.body().string());*/
       // Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");

    }

    @Test
    public void zlaunch(){

        onView(withId(R.id.next)).perform(click());
        // here i want to launch test cases of Second Activity(i.e. Test2)

    }

    @Test
    public void wrongUserId() throws IOException {

        //  Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");

        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("omoto.test11@gmail.com"));
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("password"));
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        String response = calltoBackend();
        try {
            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String resString = responseObject.getString("status");
            if (resString.equalsIgnoreCase("TABLOGINFAILED")){
                onView(withText(R.string.my_title2))
                        .inRoot(isDialog()) // <---
                        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       /* OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        okhttp3.Request request=new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();
        Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();

        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED, response.body().string());*/
        // Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");

    }

    private String calltoBackend() {
        String response = null;
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        String uid = "000000000000001";
        try {
            obj1.put(Constants.PROCESS_ID, Constants.LogInId);
            obj1.put(Constants.IMEI_ID, uid);

            //obj1.put("azureprocessid", 10);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // Constants.REG_ID = "012324354355231235435341";
           /* if (regid.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                regid = gcMutls.getRegid();
            }*/
            obj2.put(Constants.EMAIL, "omoto.test1@gmail.com");
            obj2.put(Constants.PASSWORD, "password");
            obj2.put("googleid", Constants.REG_ID);

            //obj2.put("serverkey","AIzaSyBe9FFZm0v8rcT2OZw8bjtwksM5KOIJHDg");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add(Constants.JSON_HEADER,obj1.toString())
                .add(Constants.JSON_BODY,obj2.toString())
                .build();

        okhttp3.Request request=new Request.Builder().url(Constants.BASE_URL).post(formBody).build();
        try {
            Response response1=client.newCall(request).execute();
            response = response1.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

    }

    /*@Test
    public void loginFailed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("incorrect@email.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("123456"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withText(getString(R.string.error_login_failed)))
                .inRoot(withDecorView(not(activityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }*/


  /*



    @Test
    public void loginSuccessfully_shouldShowWelcomeMessage() {
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("user@email.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("123456"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
     //   onView(withId(R.id.tv_welcome)).check(matches(withText("Hi user@email.com!")));
    }

    @Test
    public void loginSuccessfully_shouldShowToast() {
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("user@email.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("123456"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withText(getString(R.string.login_successfully)))
                .inRoot(withDecorView(not(activityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }*/

    private String getString(@StringRes int resourceId) {
        return activityTestRule.getActivity().getString(resourceId);
    }

    private static Matcher<View> withError(final String expected) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {


            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Not found error message" + expected + ", find it!");
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
                if (item instanceof EditText) {
                    return ((EditText)item).getError().toString().equals(expected);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }


}
```

test cases of Second Activity(Test2) is as follows:

```
  package venki.estest;

import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

/**
 * Created by ${venkie} on ${28/1/16}.
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class Test2 {

    private MainActivity mActivity;
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true,false);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mActivity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void emailIsInvalid() {
        // Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("invalid"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).check(matches(withError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email))));
        //  Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "after_login");
        Test3 test3 = new Test3();
        test3.emailIsInvalid();
    }

    private static Matcher<View> withError(final String expected) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {


            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Not found error message" + expected + ", find it!");
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
                if (item instanceof EditText) {
                    return ((EditText) item).getError().toString().equals(expected);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

    }

    private String getString(@StringRes int resourceId) {
        return activityTestRule.getActivity().getString(resourceId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you test same thing twice?

Even if you want to, I think its not a good approach to manually invoke a test method (of same or other activity) from within another test method. That is why these are separate tests in the first place.

However, you can include the Test2's test code into your ztest method as below:

```
@Test
public void zlaunch(){
    onView(withId(R.id.next)).perform(click());
    // here instead of launching test cases of Second Activity
    // you can copy/paste the same code from Test2 again as below

    // Spoon.screenshot(mActivity, "initial_state");
    onView(withId(R.id.user_name)).perform(typeText("invalid"),closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.submit)).perform(click());
    //and so on
}
```